# Nested Routes No Route Matches Post But Route Exist in Rake Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Updated

```
Started GET "/classifieds/12/questions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-18 10:55:27 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"classified_id"=>"12"}
  Classified Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "classifieds".* FROM "classifieds" WHERE "classifieds"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "12"]]
  Rendered questions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms

TypeError - can't convert Symbol into Integer:
```

---

I have a question model that `belongs_to :classified` and a classified model that `has_many :questions`.

Hence this relationship, I am doing a nested routes in routes.rb

```
  resources :classifieds do 
    resources :questions
  end
```

Because of the above I am getting these new routes when I do rake routes

```
 classified_questions GET    /classifieds/:classified_id/questions(.:format)                               questions#index
                                                        POST   /classifieds/:classified_id/questions(.:format)                               questions#create
                                new_classified_question GET    /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/new(.:format)                           questions#new
                               edit_classified_question GET    /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/:id/edit(.:format)                      questions#edit
                                    classified_question GET    /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/:id(.:format)                           questions#show
                                                        PUT    /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/:id(.:format)                           questions#update
                                                        DELETE /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/:id(.:format)                           questions#destroy
```

I was digging through the nested resources section in the guide. The question new should give me a form where I can post to the questions#create which allow me to post questions to the db that belongs to a specific classified ad.

In my questions table in the schema I added this hook up

```
t.integer  "classifieds_id"
```

****I do not have a classifieds controller.

This is my controller that is rendering the show method

```
class UplatzPlacesController < ApplicationController
  require 'balanced'
    helper_method :countries
  def show
    @classified=Classified.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The show.html.erb shows the classified ad to an user and at the bottom there is a link_to

```
 <%= link_to "Post a question", new_classified_question_path(@classified.id) %>
```

I generated my own questions controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
    @question = Question.new 
  end 

  def create
    @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    @classified.questions << @question
    if @question.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Question has been posted"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "It did not go through"
    end
  end
end
```

When I click the link_to I do see the form, and the url becomes this

```
classifieds/12/questions/new #shows that id got passed correctly
```

but when I click submit, I am getting this routing error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/classifieds/12/questions/new"
```

***Post does exist per the routes.

and here is my new.html.erb in views/questions

```
<%=form_for @question, :url => new_classified_question_path do |f| %>
      <fieldset>
        <ul id='posting_question_form'>
          <li>
            <%=f.label :question_body, 'Post Your Question To Seller:'%>
            <%= f.text_area :question_body, :cols=>40, :rows=>50 %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
      <div>
      <%= f.submit "Post Question", :class => 'goButton', :style => 'width:auto;float:right;' %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I did set the attributes for mass assignments in the question model

```
attr_accessible :question_body, :classifieds_id
```

It should work but it isn't.

also the app is `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong URL Helper:

```
new_classified_question_path
```

This helper leads to the `new` action of the controller `questions` nested in the `classified`. (URL Helper in Rails are structured like this:`<action>_<parent_controller>_<controller_name>_path` or ending with `_url` instead of `_path`).

You should use:

```
form_for @question, classified_questions_path(@classified) do |f|
```

---

A guide for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: @vee thanks for the plural syntax error. About the `method: :post`, I am not sure. I think that `form_for`'s default method is `:get`, gonna check that right now

Comment: @vee my bad, it is not `GET` by default, thanks for your comment!

Comment: seems like its posting correctly, but now I am getting a type error. After changing this helper, do I have to change anything in my controller methods?

Comment: What is the error message? and What is the line concerned?

Comment: It is actually the line you gave me the `form_for`. actually in my link_to I am just passing in `@classified.id` not `@classified`. nvm changing `@classified.id` didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code concerned about this error AND the line that raises the error please? @Jngai1297

Answer (score 0):

On your new controller, should build of a new question

```
# GET /classifieds/:classified_id/questions/new
def new
  # 1st you retrieve the classified to params[:classified_id]
  @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])     
  # 2nd you build a new one of question
  @question = @classified.questions.build
end

# POST /classifieds/:classified_id/questions
def create
  # 1st you retrieve the classified to params[:classified_id]
  @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
  #2nd you create the question with arguments in params[:question]
  @question = @classified.questions.create(params[:question])
  respond_to do |format|
   if @question.save 
     # redirection to the Question resource
     format.html { redirect_to([@question.classified, @question], :notice => 'Question has been posted.')
     # or redirection to the list of Questions
     # redirect_to(classified_@questions_url)
   else
     format.html { 
       flash[:error] = "It did not go through"
       render :action => "new" 
     } 
   end
  end
end
```

And on new form

```
<%= form_for([@question.classified, @question]) do |f| %>
   ....
<% end %>
```

Another way of creating nested resources : [Creating nested resources in ruby on rails 3 and updating scaffolding links and redirection](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080)